# Trying to see what options are pre-configured with another site's Ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

So I basically have a rails app that is loading another full page in Ckeditor, but it's having a ton of issues trying to render the HTML. The styling is different, lots of text is being manipulated and swapped around, etc.

However, there's another app that uses ckeditor and the site renders just fine for it. I've tried hunting through the source code to see how the ckeditor is initialized, but the only thing I see is `$("#html_editor").ckeditor();` which doesn't appear that any extra options are being loaded.

Just trying to find some other ways to determine why my ckeditor isn't displaying HTMl pages properly even though I'm initializing it the same way.

I've tried enabling the `fullPage` option, but it still looks extremely weird (things are completely misplaced), etc.

Looking for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Found it after hunting down a default config.js that contains default options when loading CKEditor